# Get substring between strings from a python list

Tags: python

How to get the content between strings `&quot` and `autoRefresh` which will be `/commander/link/jobDetails/jobs/a2537f238-8622-11ee-a1a0-f0921c14c828?` from a list as below, I just need the first match (there could be multiple matches).

```
['something', 'something', ' something top.window.location.href = &quot;/commander/link/jobDetails/jobs/a2537f238-8622-11ee-a1a0-f0921c14c828?autoRefresh=0&amp;s=Jobs&quot;;">','something']
```

Tried

```
link = re.search('&quot;(.*?)autoRefresh', big_list)
print link.group(1)
```

and got `TypeError: expected string or buffer`

Comment: You passed a list when it should be each string in a loop or use `"".join(big_list)`

Comment: do `for elem in big_list: print re.search(...).group(1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate over the list, checking each string:

```
big_list = ['something', 'something', ' something top.window.location.href = &quot;/commander/link/jobDetails/jobs/a2537f238-8622-11ee-a1a0-f0921c14c828?autoRefresh=0&amp;s=Jobs&quot;;">','something']

def get_all_subs(lst, pat, grp=0):
    patt = re.compile(pat)
    for s in lst:
        m = patt.search(s, grp)
        if m:
            yield m.group(grp)

print(list(get_all_subs(big_list, '&quot;(.*?)autoRefresh', 1)))
```

Or call `str.join` on the list and use *findall*:

```
print(re.findall('&quot;(.*?)autoRefresh', "".join(big_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following:

```
re.search(r'(?<=&quot).*?(?=autoRefresh)', ''.join(YourList))
```

Comment: its a very big list, so let me iterate through and break out of loop after the match. thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Didn't get it.